# Entity Framework Reverse POCO

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, poco, edmx

We have an existing Db with about 100 odd tables - These were created the old way - use sql queries to generate the Db and use the SQL reader/writer to access and update the DB's.( ADO.net). A developer prior to me added few new tables to this using the EntityFramework (EDMX) approach. They just named the tables generated newly "DBEntities" and used this as a data source for the new pages that were then written in ASP. net webforms(apsx).

I am now tasked with developing some of the newer pages on this existing webforms app to be built in Angular 2.0. I started off with consolidating the one DB that this app reads ( which were referencing both the EDMX file and ado.net - having two config file entries - add name ="DbConn" connection string "".. and add name="DBEntities" the edmx conn string".) I removed the edmx files , used the reverse poco generator and created first class POCO's and generated my tt file. Updated my web config to include only one connection string "DBConn". Tested the app - all the old web form pages were working well. Only those aspx pages(controls that use DataBind..) that were referencing the EDMX files gave me this error - The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

I have tried everything(regenrated POCO's.. checked all the table names against the aspx data sources everything looks good..) and nothing seems to work. Using EF6. - Any help is appreciated..

Thanks much.

Comment: What about your context? Did you replace that with the reverse engineered version as well? Show your context and the connection string it is referring to. Also, is Entity Framework in the web project or a separate library?

Comment: Thank you. Turns out that the webforms(aspx pages) were using an obsolete data provider - EntityDataSource - this did not work well with code first DB as a data source while trying to configure it in the aspx page - so I removed them from here and configured the data source in the code behind and it all worked fine then.